# numpy where with different sizes

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a for loop which takes more than 1 hour to be executed , so i had the idea to use the numpy.where() function instead .
I want to know if there is any way to use the numpy where inside an array with different sublists sizes like the example below  :

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
a = np.array(a)
print(np.where(a < 3, -1, 100))
```

Output :

```
 File "test.py", line 104, in <module>
        print(np.where(a < 3, -1, 100))
   TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The point is that array `a` you have defined is not uniform and therefore is been treated like a list. You might want to make it uniform to make it work or else you will not be able to get benefits of numpy.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer ! 
what you mean exactly with uniform ? 
you mean something like this [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]? 
if yes i cant use different list sizes  ?

Comment: In fact i have an array with subarrays each one have the pixels of an Image and those images don't have the same shapes , so the sizes of the arrays may differ 
Do you have any idea how can i use where in this case ?

Comment: Hi Wassim, I made an answer for you for this specific case. However, if you provide additional details on your code, I'm sure you'll get a bunch of interesting ideas on how to speed-up you code.

Comment: The condition as a python argument is evaluated in full before being passed to the `where`.  `where` is a function, not a special syntax operation.

Comment: Look at your `a`.  It's an array of lists!  What do you think you've gained?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a list comprehension it should be faster than a FOR loop:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
print([list(np.where(np.array(x) < 3, -1, 100)) for x in a])
```

Output:

```
[[-1, -1, 100], [100, 100]]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the Answer ! 
thats a good Idea i will try it , but i think it will take too long to. 
In fact i have an array with subarrays each one have the pixels of an Image and those images don't have the same shapes , so the sizes of the sub-arrays may differ Do you have any idea how can i use the where in this case?

Comment: This highly depends on what you do with those images maybe you can add to the question what operations do you perform on each of the images. If you are doing image processing I don't think it is this loop that slows down the process. It is probably the treatment that you apply to each image that takes time.

Comment: well im replacing some pixels with some input weights for example 
[[1,10,5],[1,6,7]...]
i need to replace all occurences of 10 with the value 99
and all occurences of 6 with 98

Comment: In my experience list comprehension only makes a modest speed improvement, especially if the loop action is complex

Comment: @hpaulj Yes you are right. However, I don't know how the original version that takes more than an hour is implemented. Of course, list comprehension makes a modest speed improvement ahgainst a good for loop implementation.